Split a string into rows by delimiter and add column with order
I know how to split a string into rows by a delimiter from



V1
V2




1
h,e


2
l,l,o



to



V1
V2




1
h


1
e


2
l


2
l


2
o



with tidyr::separate_longer_delim(V2, delim = ",") but how can I add a column with the original order of the individual string parts as in



V1
V2
order




1
h
1


1
e
2


2
l
1


2
l
2


2
o
3



?

Using purrr::map to get the order variable, then unnest to get the elements per row
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(V2 = strsplit(V2, ","), 
         order = purrr::map(lengths(V2), ~ seq_len(.x))) %>% 
  unnest(-V1)
# A tibble: 5 × 3
     V1 V2    order
  <int> <chr> <int>
1     1 h         1
2     1 e         2
3     2 l         1
4     2 l         2
5     2 o         3

Data
df <- structure(list(V1 = 1:2, V2 = c("h,e", "l,l,o")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -2L))


Thank you so much, this works perfectly!

Add the mutate line shown.  dat is defined reproducibly in the Note at the end.
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>%
  separate_longer_delim(V2, delim = ",") %>%
  mutate(V2, order = row_number(), .by = V1)

giving
  V1 V2 order
1  1  h     1
2  1  e     2
3  2  l     1
4  2  l     2
5  2  o     3

Note
Input.  Run this first.
dat <- data.frame(V1 = 1:2, V2 = c("h,e", "l,l,o"))


base R
assuming V1 is no id-column.
> i = strsplit(df0$V2, ",", fixed = TRUE); n = lengths(i)
> data.frame(V1 = rep(df0$V1, n), V2 = unlist(i), O = unlist(lapply(n, seq)))
  V1 V2 O
1  1  h 1
2  1  e 2
3  2  l 1
4  2  l 2
5  2  o 3


Note
df0 = structure(list(V1 = 1:2, V2 = c("h,e", "l,l,o")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

